# jQuery dataTable 1.7.6 refresh table without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to refresh table data on ajax form submit how to do without reloading page . I'm using data table 1.7.6

I;m using datatable 1.7.6 in below is initiation

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the `dataTable` initialization. Also, 1.7.6 is deprecated.

Comment: @philantrovert : I've update my question

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax.reload

```
 $('#table-id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Comment: Note that he's using Datatables 1.7.6. `ajax.reload()` got introduced in `DataTable 1.10`

Comment: @Tharu perera y u r using Older version of plugin?

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh : any suggessions to do this with 1.7.6 ?

Comment: No sorry bro ;)

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the datatable

```
$('#teamTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

update contents.
then ,

Reinitalize it ..

```
 $('#teamTable').dataTable();
```

Comment: ive update my question with my current code. pls check and advice me

Answer (score -1):

Since, you are working with Datatable 1.7.6 `ajax.reload()` will not work for you. Luckily, the author created a plugin before he introduced `ajax.reload`
You need this plugin called [`fnReloadAjax`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax)

Implementation is there on the page too.

It'd go something along the lines of:

```
var oTable = $("#usertable").dataTable ({ 
     //your options
     //more options
});
```

And then to reload:

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

Though, if you can, try to upgrade to 1.10.

Use [this](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10) and [this](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert)

Comment: I'm getting fnReloadAjax is not a function(…)

Comment: You need to download that script and add it on your HTML page. Study the link carefully. It's all written there. :)

Comment: yes I've added that script link to my page which showing datatable. and  added "oTable.fnReloadAjax();" to my dialog box submit function. still same :(

Comment: I have added that to my question as well .can u check

Comment: : can you help me

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? `fnReloadAjax is not a function(...)`?

Comment: try initialising `var oTable = ''` as a global variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130024/discussion-between-philantrovert-and-tharu-perera).

Comment: can u check this as well pls

Comment: @Tharuperera see what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020210/adding-spinner-till-content-load-inside-dialog-box need help