# Adding spinner till content load inside dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dialog box for load a form , contents loading from external url take some time to load. therefore how can I add a spinner loader to show till content loading.

Comment: Seems like you're using some additional libraries/plugins other than jQuery-- what are those?  We'll need to know to see if there are promises/callbacks that can be leveraged for that purpose.

Comment: @anied : I've added a screenshot. those plugins are loading.

Comment: @anied : Is it possible to add alert to show   alert('Still loading, please wait just a second longer'); till the content load

Comment: What is your plugin that is providing `.dialog`?  I'd recommend exploring [`.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `.load` and leveraging the success/error callbacks.

Comment: @anied : replace .load with .ajax? it didn't work. please advice

Comment: I didn't mean to simply switch it-- there are examples in the documentation of how to leverage the success callback.  Can you please state which plugin is providing the `.dialog` method?  This will be helpful in providing an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery)